# Laurent expansion of $\sin(z)^{-2y}$ at $z=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have tried a lot to generalize this thread: [Laurent series of $\frac1{\sin^2z}$ around 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227783/laurent-series-of-frac1-sin2z-around-0) but I am not able to compute the coefficients of the principal part (that is what I am interested in). Help would be appreciated.

PS: this is no homework problem

Comment: You can write the coefficients [in terms of the Bell polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3937502).

Comment: @Maxim Can you elaborate? Maybe I am just stupid, but I cannot comprehend how to write the coefficients in terms of the Bell polynomials. Thanks in advance!